# How to use Python read a text file and transfer to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, text, file-read

```
1. How do you like this product?
As someone who wears glasses for distance, but not contacts I have struggled with vision on the slopes
At this price, I'm very happy with the B1. They were very comfortable
I wore these all winter for 10 weeks of skiing!
These are cheap in price yes but they do what they're supposed to
2. Do you have any recommendations?
The product is a defect, and the quality was bad
Yes, I like this product and it didn't fog up when I was skiing
I won't refer my friend to buy this product.
So far so good
```

I'm trying to read a txt file that looks like above and I want to transfer it to a dictionary.
Questions as keys and followed by four reviews as values.

```
{"1. How do you like this product?":["As someone who wears glasses for distance, but not contacts I have struggled with vision on the slopes","At this price, I'm very happy with the B1. They were very comfortable","I wore these all winter for 10 weeks of skiing!","These are cheap in price yes but they do what they're supposed to","As someone who wears glasses for distance, but not contacts I have struggled with vision on the slopes"],"2. Do you have any recommendations?":["The product is a defect, and the quality was bad","Yes, I like this product and it didn't fog up when I was skiing","I won't refer my friend to buy this product.","So far so good"]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried any code yet? Please include your best attempt at it, and mention at what step you are stuck. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open('file') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    key = None
    for line in lines:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            key = line
            d[line] = []
        else:
            d[key].append(line)
```

Comment: Hi Kuba, Thank you for the help. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your criteria for a *question* is. Here I assume that a question ends with `?`

```
with open('input_file.txt') as f:
  out_dict = {}
  for line in f.readlines():
    # strip out blank characters at the beginning and the end
    line = line.strip()

    # a question ends with ?
    if line[:-1] == '?':
       current_key=line
       out_dict[current_key] = []
    else:
       out_dict[current_key].append(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Not all questions end up with a "?" actually.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but this code works:

```
outputDict = {}
with open('sampleText', 'r') as f:
    tempKey = None
    templist = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0].isdigit() and line[1] == '.':
            if tempKey != None:
                outputDict[tempKey] = templist
                templist = []
                tempKey = line.rstrip('\n')
                print('found a key that is not the first')
                print(line)
                print(tempKey)
            else:
                tempKey = line.rstrip('\n')
                print('found first key')
                print(line)
                print(tempKey)
        else:
            templist.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
            print('found val')
            print(line)
    outputDict[tempKey] = templist
```